# AWS - Display all connected users in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This is WEBSOCKET API. I am very new to this.

So I have this command in CLI which connects to the api gateway and store the username(Zeus) in dynamodb

```
wscat -c [wssURL]?username=Zeus
```

It should return the username/s in CLI that is/are connected to the API Gateway. This is my lambda that is connected to a route in my API Gateway.

```
exports.handler = async function(event, context, callback) {
   // let sender = JSON.parse(event.body).sender;
    let scannedItems = await displayUsers();
    console.log(scannedItems);
    callback(null, {
        statusCode: 200
     });
    return {};
};

async function displayUsers() {    
    return ddb.scan(
        {  
        TableName: 'Chat',
        ProjectionExpression: "username"
    }).promise();
}

How can I return my scannedItems in the CLI?
```

Comment: So what is not working? What is the problem?

Comment: There's no output. It should return all the username/s that are in the database when {"action": "myroutehere"}

Comment: You arent returning anything...

Answer (score 1):

Your handler is not returning the `scannedItems` variable, just logging it in CloudWatch.

Comment: Hello. How can I return the scannedItems in CLI?